# OpenLayer map markers don't works

Tags: javascript, openlayers, markers

hi i'm using Openlayer map this is my script , map is ok but the markers  wouldn't works:

```
 var map = new OpenLayers.Map ('open_map', { 
      controls:[ 
      new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation()
      ],
      projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"),
      displayProjection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326")
    });
     var lonLat = new OpenLayers.LonLat(_json.lon, _json.lat).transform (
    new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), // transform from WGS 1984
    map.getProjectionObject() // to Spherical Mercator Projection
);

     var markers = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers( "Markers" );
     map.addLayer(markers);

     var size = new OpenLayers.Size(16,27);
     var offset = new OpenLayers.Pixel(-(size.w/2), -size.h);
     var icon = new OpenLayers.Icon('http://www.google.com/mapfiles/marker.png', size, offset);
     markers.addMarker(new OpenLayers.Marker(lonLat, icon.clone()));

     var mapnik = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM("Test");
     map.addLayer(mapnik);

     map.setCenter (lonLat, 5 /* zoom lvl */);

   console.log(lonLat);
console.log(_json.lon);
console.log(_json.lat);
```

this is the console log:

[image]
when i do not use markers the map zoom is exactly in the lon and lat i pass, while if i use marker the marker is putted really outside of the place they needs to be on.

does anyone has suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently you are:

1. creating markers from original coordinates
2. transforming coordinates from 4326 to 900913 and using them to center map.

In what system are your coordinates in _json object? In case, they are EPSG:4325 (from -180 to 180 or 0 to 360), create markers from transformed coordinates:

```
var lonLat = new OpenLayers.LonLat(_json.lon, _json.lat).transform (
    new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), // transform from WGS 1984
    new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913") // to Spherical Mercator Projection
    // map.getProjectionObject() doesn't work for unknown reason
);

markers.addMarker(new OpenLayers.Marker(lonLat, icon));
markers.addMarker(new OpenLayers.Marker(lonLat, icon.clone()));

map.setCenter (lonLat, 5 /* zoom lvl */);
```

PS, is there any particular reason to create two markers to same place:

```
markers.addMarker(new OpenLayers.Marker(lonLat, icon.clone()));
```

Comment: i just copied the openlayer official site example

Comment: i edited my question now marker works but it is putted out of lon and lat i pass to lotLan var

Comment: That's really wierd: map.getProjectionObject() returns null. Use new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913") instead, and it seems to work. I also modified original answer.

Comment: yep now it works, anyway should be great to understand what appens, so strange :P